# Lightroom Classic v12.1 error: A change in Develope remove all Fujifilm metadata

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing, metadata, fujifilm, error

Lightroom Classic v12.1 error: Any change in Develope removed all Fujifilm metadata (Exif tags) when saved.

When comparing a jpg file from my X-H2s camera by ExifTool, the following where missing after editing in Lr:

Quality, Clarity, Crop Mode, Film Mode, Flicker Reduction
Blur Warning, Exposure Warning, Focus Warning
Faces Detected, Picture Mode
Focus Mode, Focus Mode 2, Focus Pixel
Noise Reduction, Num Face Elements
Fuji Flash Mode, Fuji Model, Fuji Model 2
Sequence Number, Shutter Speed Value, Shutter Type, Slow Sync
and all 18 Fuji Film 0xnnnn tags

Anybody discovered the same problem?

Comment: Probably this query should rather be directed towards Adobe Support, or at least to the Adobe community forums

Comment: Yes, I have done and they said it will be looked into.
So hopefully Fujifilm metadata will be recognized in a near future reklease.

Answer (score 1):

Most of that info is included in the "maker notes" section of the EXIF Info.

Adobe products are notorious for ignoring/stripping most of the maker notes information when converting native raw files to DNG and when exporting converted raw files to standardized formats such as TIFF, JPEG, PNG, etc.

What you are describing is not that surprising based on the way Adobe products have long treated what they term as "undocumented" maker notes information.

Comment: There was a very informative statement by an Adobe employee on their forums a few years ago regarding this. I don't have time right now to see if I can track down the original thread on Adobe's updated "support community", but here's the now defunct address of the old link. The old thread number *might* still be valid somewhere in the new community forum. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/743437?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: That thread is accessible through the Internet Archive: [Lightroom strips very valuable EXIF data - details](https://web.archive.org/web/20141205135721/https://forums.adobe.com/thread/743437)

Comment: `You can't just shove EXIFTool into Lr; this is not how it works.` - hysterical.